# Help Me To Translate This After Effects Expression!

Tags: adobe, after-effects-expressions

```
wiggle(effect("Ondulación - posición")("Velocidad ondulación (ond/seg)"), effect("Ondulación - posición")("Cantidad ondulación (píxeles)"))
```

How to translate this expression?

Answer (score 0):

Translate this:

wiggle(effect("Ondulación - posición")("Velocidad ondulación (ond/seg)"), effect("Ondulación - posición")("Cantidad ondulación (píxeles)")

My best try:
Given wiggle/effect is English 
wiggle(effect("wave - position")("wave speed{velocity})(wave/seconds{seg=segundos})"),effect("{..repeated...}")("wave amount/size ({in} pixels)") 
{} my comment 
Where/what do you get this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the default text for the wiggle property?

```
wiggle(freq, amp, octaves = 1, amp_mult = .5, t = time)
```

So the shortened terms are

- Frequency
- Amplitude
- Octaves
- Amplitude Multiplier
- Time

You can see this by:

1. Make a layer
2. Alt or Option-click on the Position control on that layer
3. Click on the Expression Language Menu (it's a little solid circle with a triangle inside).
4. Choose Property --> Wiggle